# if else rails syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ':'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this code:

```
<% if @lead? -%>
    <h3>Current status of your car is <%= @lead.status %> </h3>
    <%=image_tag("stat/" + @lead.status + ".jpg", :class => "status_image", alt: "status")%>
<% else -%>
    <h3> No records found.</h3>
<% end -%>
```

What I want to do is to check if my @lead exists and show lead and some picture or say that such records in db were not found. But it gives me an error:

> /home/jonstark/rails_projects/car_main/app/views/static_pages/check_lead_car_status.html.erb:4:
>   syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ':' ...urrent status of your
>   car is ';@output_buffer.append=( @lead...

If I take away if else and leave just this:

```
<h3>Current status of your car is <%= @lead.status %> </h3><br/><br/>
        <%=image_tag("stat/" + @lead.status + ".jpg", :class => "status_image", alt: "status")%>
```

The error dissapears.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
<% if @lead %>
    <h3>Current status of your car is <%= @lead.status %> </h3>
    <%=image_tag("stat/" + @lead.status + ".jpg", :class => "status_image", alt: "status")%>
<% else %>
    <h3> No records found.</h3>
<% end %>
```

This should work and fix your problem.

Comment: yeah I didn't accept it immediately cause I had 7 min delay before accepting=)